# VPN on Linux - IP routing issue

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, routing

I got the following scenario:

an ubuntu server 20.04 lts, for simplicity named A server with the following network interfaces:

- loopback
- enp1s0 (wan) PUBLIC-IP/23
- enp8s0 (lan) 10.9.96.3/20
- ppp0 (l2tp) 192.168.42.1

with this routing table (public routes are intentionally omitted):

- 10.9.96.0/20 dev enp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.96.3
- 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.42.10 dev ppp0
- 192.168.42.10 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.1

There's a remote vpn client connected with ip 192.168.42.10.
This client is a MikroTik router providing the remote lan network 192.168.1.0/24
Using the static route added by me (192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.42.10 dev ppp0) I am able to reach out 192.168.1.0/24 devices.

---

another ubuntu server 20.04 lts, for simplicity named B server with the following network interfaces:

- loopback
- enp1s0 (wan) PUBLIC-IP/23
- enp8s0 (lan) 10.9.96.4/20

and this routing table (public routes are intentionally omitted):

- 10.9.96.0/20 dev enp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.96.4

Basically I need to access 192.168.1.0/24 devices from server B but I cannot make it work. 
 I've also tried to add a static route: 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.9.96.3 dev enp8s0

 within this server without success, I see packets destined to 192.168.1.X reaching out server A but then they are not forwarded to ppp0 interface I guess (so I've tried also some iptables rules)

How to fix this issue?

Firewall is disabled in both servers.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: In this answer, the network `100.64.10.0/23` represents the public network. It's not particularly relevant but exists only to make the network configuration of these virtual nodes match what you've described in your question.

---

Your problem is that hosts on the 192.168.1.0/24 network don't know how to reach the 10.9.96.0/20 network.

Based on what you've shown us in your question, the routing table on the microtik router (192.168.42.10/192.168.1.1) probably looks something like this:

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev h1-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
192.168.42.0/24 dev h1-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.10
```

And the routing table on serverA looks something like:

```
default via 100.64.10.1 dev serverA-eth0
10.9.96.0/20 dev serverA-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.96.3
100.64.10.0/23 dev serverA-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 100.64.10.10
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.42.10 dev serverA-eth2
192.168.42.0/24 dev serverA-eth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.1
```

On `serverA`, when you ping an address on the `192.168.1.0/24` network, your source address is `192.168.42.1`. The microtik router has a route for that network, so everything is great.

If on `serverB` you have a routing table like this:

```
default via 100.64.10.1 dev serverB-eth0
10.9.96.0/20 dev serverB-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.96.4
100.64.10.0/23 dev serverB-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 100.64.10.20
192.168.1.0/24 via 10.9.96.3 dev serverB-eth1
```

Then when you try to connect to an address on the `192.168.1.0/24` network, your source address will be `10.9.96.4`. The microtik router doesn't know how to reach that address (or it attempts to respond via the default gateway, which is inappropriate).

The solution is to add a route to the microtik router like this:

```
ip route add 10.9.96.0/20 via 192.168.42.1
```

Now:

- ServerB can ping the microtik router because the microtik router has a valid route back to serverB
- ServerB can ping *other* hosts on the `192.168.1.0/24` network because those hosts use the microtik router (`192.168.1.1`) as their default gateway...and as established in the previous bullet point, the router has an appropriate route.

---

I tested all of this in a simulated network environment built using [mininet](http://mininet.org/); you can find the configuration [here](https://github.com/larsks/sf-example-1143985-routing) if you're curious.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Mikrotik router already knows how to reach 10.9.96.0/20, indeed I can ping 10.9.96.3 (server A) but not 10.9.96.4 (server B) don't know why.
Anyway issue persists. I am not able to ping any 192.168.1.0/24 device from server B